# How to pass parameters in socket.io server from hoppscotch.io client

Tags: socket.io, client, query-string, hoppscotch

I've a server running with [socket.io](https://socket.io) and I was in search of socket.io client tool (since postman doesn't have it) to test the backend code and got to know about [hoppscotch.io](https://hoppscotch.io/realtime).

But, I'm not able to find from where to pass the **token (or any data)** from **hoppscotch.io socket client**.

There is one tool named [amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/) I found and it works as it has option to pass the parameters. But I just wanted to use hoppscotch.io

Please let me know if we can pass the parameters in hoppscotch.io or there is any other socket client tool available.

Comment: what form of authentication did you add to your server ?

Comment: It's jwt authentication